# jQuery $('#mydiv').css('top','500'); not working

Tags: jquery, css

With:

```
#mydiv{ position:relative; }
```

When I execute:

```
$('#mydiv').css('top','500');
```

Is not working, I'm not getting errors at all.

Basically what I need to do is move (not animate) that DIV 500px up, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: is the css attribute "position" of your div set to either relative or absolute ?

Comment: You have a dollar sign "$mydiv" instead of a pound sign "#mydiv" is that a typo on here or in your code as well?

Comment: what kind of errors do you get? and if you want to move it up, than it should be `-500px`.

Answer (score 2):

Telling it to set top: to 500px is going to move it down 500px from the relative position, not go up. You should be using a negative number, -500px for instance.

Comment: the `px` after the number is important, since there are multiple metrics in css you must specify the metric you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

Moving it 500 px up:

First get the current position (this one is relative to the parent)

```
var topPosition = $('#mydiv').position().top;
```

Then move it

```
$('#mydiv').css('top',(topPosition - 500) + 'px');
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to use 500px instead of just 500

Comment: You should try to be a little more descriptive with your answers.  Try to help the poster understand why?

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery .css function updates the top value but the changes are not reflected in screen.

Use $('#mydiv').offset({top: 500}); It will update the top value both in DOM and screen.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the '$' doesn't mean anything in a jQuery selection string. If you're trying to find the div with the id 'mydiv', use:

```
$('#mydiv').css('top', '500');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#mydiv').css('top','500');
```

Note the pound sign (#) preceding the ID. You're using the dollar sign ($).

Answer (score 0):

couple of things
1. you have a typo it should be #mydiv and not $mydiv (in the js part)
2. check with firebug if the element is being changed after the command is being executed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to have #myDiv as the jQuery selector: `$("#myDiv")`

And, if I remember right, your div container (parent) needs to be:

```
position: relative;
```

and your "#myDiv" needs to be:

```
position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure jQuery is working? Also, make sure it isn't being loaded more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Jquery is loading in firebug. For testing also add an alert to make sure 
$(function(){
alert('Jquery is loading');
});

If Jquery is loading, try this $('#mydiv').css({'top':'500px'});

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS, after seting position: absolute; try to set "top:0px;". It may help.